# Vertical Menu/Navigation- Wordpress/JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, jsfiddle

I am trying to put a vertical menu in to one of my Wordpress pages. I've coded it exactly how I want it to work and function in JSFiddle, but for some reason, when I copy the code in to Wordpress, it does not work.

How can I get this to work? I am so frustrated. I've been researching this now for a month.

Here is a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PEZman777/5pkcH/6/ and a sample of the HTML code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="aboutnav">
        <div align="right"><a href="#a">Company Overview</a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="aboutnav">
        <div align="right"><a href="#b">About Us</a></div>
    </li>
     <li class="aboutnav">
         <div align="right"><a href="#c">Contact Us</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="a">
    Content of A
</div>
<div id="b">
    Content of B
</div>
<div id="c">
    Content of C
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the page I want to put this menu on: http://www.cedarstreetcommercial.com/about-us/

Comment: In the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish'" I also see THREE versions of jQuery being loaded (!).

Comment: @isherwood what do you mean by this?

Comment: Which part don't you understand? You have an error in the browser console, and you're loading 3 flavors of jQuery which are probably colliding with each other. I'd fix those issues first.

Comment: @isherwood I removed the javascript script code in the HTML page. It no longer shows the superfish error, but it is still not working. Can you suggest something that would help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of timing, sometimes called a "race condition". If I run your jQuery in the console it works fine. You're running your tabs init function in the head of the document, before the page is rendered. Either move it to the bottom of the HTML body, or wrap it in a document.ready function:

```
    ...

    <script>
    //shorthand for jQuery(document).ready() { and with an alias for $
    jQuery(function($) { 
        $('#tabs')
        .tabs()
        .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Should I put this code directly in to the HTML page or should I add this into the <head> section of the header.php?

Comment: That's a matter of personal preference (with minor performance implications unique to your site). Either will work as I've written it.

Comment: This is presently what I have in my header.php file:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#tabs')
    .tabs()
    .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
</script>`

Comment: No, it isn't. I've explained the difference in my answer.

Comment: It isn't the same, rather. I can see what's in your page with my own eyes. :-)

Comment: Since jQuery 1.10 is already loaded, you should take that call out.

Comment: Actually, jQ 1.10 is being loaded twice, too. You really need to examine all the stuff in your page head. Chrome's source view lets you click into each file to see versions, etc.

Comment: I'm not an expert, I apologize, I am very confused. I stripped the code that I previously had in the header.php, but unfortunately it did not work. Then I went ahead and added this code (exactly) to the bottom of the HTML body ... didn't work ... what am I doing wrong? I appreciate EVERYTHING you've helped me with thus far ... I should note that :)

Comment: This is way over my head ... grrrr :(

Comment: I don't see the tabs function in the body. I've updated my answer to better indicate what it should look like.

Comment: Thank you!
I've amended the <body> with the provided code. It works, but for some reason, it does not look how it does in JSFiddle. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You probably have some CSS from the rest of the site interfering. I'm out of time for the day, though. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: You da man @isherwood!!!!

Comment: thanks again for all your help yesterday. I got everything working PERFECTLY in Google Chrome, but for some reason, the sub menu in Firefox and Internet Explorer is cut off. Why is this happening? Is there an easy to fix this? I tried adding style margins/padding, but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Figured it out ... missing a float:right tag.